# Combine PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE results

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I'm splitting a string following this format:

```
| + anything goes here + single space
```

The following regular expression corresponds to said pattern:

```
/(\|\S*)/
```

Using `preg_split` with `PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE` oddly returns the delimiter into two parts. Is there a flag or option to combine these resulting outputs?

```
$string = "|one |two |three this is a phrase |four";
$result = preg_split('/(\|\S*)/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

What I get:

```
array(7) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "|one"
  [1]=>
  string(1) " "
  [2]=>
  string(4) "|two"
  [3]=>
  string(1) " "
  [4]=>
  string(6) "|three"
  [5]=>
  string(18) " this is a phrase "
  [6]=>
  string(5) "|four"
}
```

What I want:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "|one "
  [1]=>
  string(5) "|two "
  [2]=>
  string(7) "|three "
  [3]=>
  string(17) "this is a phrase "
  [4]=>
  string(5) "|four"
}
```

Comment: `string(7) "|three "` [...] `string(18) " this is a phrase "`, Did you realize you doubled the number of spaces? (between `three` and `this`), is this purposeful? Shouldn't you get `"this is a phrase "` instead?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I was about to correct it but you got to it first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply catch another whitespace at the end of the word, and you'll get this:

```
/(\|\S*\h*)/ || /(\|\S*\s*)/
```

So your code will be:

```
<?php
$string = "|one |two |three this is a phrase |four";
$result = preg_split('/(\|\S*\s*)/', $string, NULL, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY | 
PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
var_dump ($result);
```

Regex 101: https://regex101.com/r/m5M7Dv/1

### Result

```
array(5) { [0]=> string(5) "|one " [1]=> string(5) "|two " [2]=> string(7) "|three " [3]=> string(17) "this is a phrase " [4]=> string(5) "|four" }
```

Comment: Ah, it's my regex that's faulty. Thank you for your time!